# Do the four Chinese symbols in the bottom-left corner of a Samsung battery mean manufacturing date? (Characters identified: 生产日期)

Tags: translation, character-identification

For the purpose of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/81178/20449) I'd like to know whether the four Chinese characters in the bottom-left corner of the i9250 Samsung battery really mean manufacturing date:

[image]

[Here](http://www.acebattery.ca/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/cellbatt/c34.jpg), [here](http://cdn.shopclues.com/images/detailed/603/AAA10071071j_1381905850.jpg) or [here](http://www.trait-tech.com/uploads/details/T-SSI9250-1__.jpg) are high-resolution images of the battery, which should be easier to read and confirm.

I am more than sure whether these four symbols actually mean that, so I only need a confirmation, since I don't know Chinese at all.

*Disclaimer: I understand and full accept FAQ's regulation, claiming, that questions asking for translations are off-topic in this site. I think I did enough prior research. I only need a confirmation, not a translation.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it writes 「生产日期」 which means manufacture date.